# Ajax reload page with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I new in rails, and i can't understand how to rewrite next functionality.

For example:
I have a list of products.
And every product has some field ( category )

```
   def index
    if params[:select_query]
      @posts = Post.selecting(params[:select_query])
    else
      @posts = Post.all   
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Index.html

```
<%= select_tag "credit_card", options_for_select([["first", 1], ["second", 2], ["third", 3]], 2) %>
<div class='tab'>
  <%= render 'table' %>
</div>

<%= link_to 'Select', posts_path(select_query: 'first'), class: 'link', remote: true %>
```

Index.js.erb

```
$('.tab').html("<%= j render 'table' %>")
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('#credit_card').on('change', function(){
        variable = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('.link').attr('href', '/posts?select_query='+variable).click();
    });
});
```

I try to realise same functionality but without additional link ( button )

In perfect way i should have only JS file ( with Ajax )

Could help me **rewrite** this functionality by ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
$('#credit_card').on('change', function(){
  var variable = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/posts',
    data: {select_query: variable },
    dataType: 'JS'});
});
```

Or if you don't want the js.erb at all. You can rewrite your controller as:

```
# ...
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.js { render partial: 'table' }
end
```

And add success handler for your ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/posts',
  data: {select_query: variable },
  success: function(result) {
    $('.tab').html(result);
  },
  dataType: 'JS'});
```

Comment: i added 1 way, 2 way - but it does not work at all. =( ( method on('change', fun... works correctly - but ajax does not reload page ( i copy ajax function as in your example

Comment: @DemitriyDN Could you show me the request and response of the AJAX request?

Comment: )))) thanks. i find my mistake -> should be $('.tab').html(result.responseText);

Comment: and a change status from success to complete ( i still do not understand why success does not work =) ) but "complete" works fine.

Comment: Hi @DemitriyDN, the `complete` callback is called after the `success` or `error` finished, so maybe in your case the AJAX request was not success, your code might work but not in the right way, could you check the status of the request? I also recheck and see that if it's success, the code to update page will be `$('.tab').html(result);`

Answer (score 0):

You could also add `success: window.location.reload()` to you ajax call